# 01 Chevy impala

Tags: electrical

My car won't do anything when I turn the key no lights or nothin, battery is new, alternator good new starter , but if I hook cables up to the side post battery it will turn over and when it starts it runs good no lights come on accept the security light on dash stay on but I have no remote for that also sometimes the turn signal lights work and sometimes after a jump it don't and sometimes when I turn the car off the motor will shut off but dash lights still b on intell I turn tv off what could the problem be? And the thermal is touching the battery

Comment: Also follow those heavy cables and re-new the connections at the far end.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you have the cable screwed onto the side post does not mean it's getting a good connection. I have seen it many times where the connection will not be made. You need to ensure you haven't stripped out the threads in the side post holes, nor off terminal bolt itself. This will give you a loose connection which is not enough to make contact. You can check your connections between the cables and battery by grabbing the cables and seeing if they wiggle. It is either this or the battery is bad (or not filled with electrolytes). You can check the battery itself to see if there is a charge by using a multi-meter or taking it to Autozone or any other parts place for a load test. If using a multi-meter, the battery should be around 12.5-13.5 vdc. Sounds weird for a 12v battery to have 12.5+ volts, but that's the way it works.